# Disposing client after creation with WebChannelFactory

Tags: c#, wcf, dispose, webchannelfactory

In my current production code, and according to [documentation on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb472541%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#sectionSection1), the way to create a client is this

```
using (WebChannelFactory<IServiceInterface> cf
      = new WebChannelFactory<IServiceInterface>("http://service.url"))
{
    IServiceInterface client = cf.CreateChannel();
    client.CallTheMethod();
}
```

given that I have this interface:

```
public interface IServiceInterface
{
    void CallTheMethod();
}
```

However I noticed that the object client created by the WebChannelFactory also implements IDisposable. So I want to dispose this object also. I didn't find any other way than:

```
using (WebChannelFactory<IServiceInterface> cf
      = new WebChannelFactory<IServiceInterface>("http://service.url"))
using(IDisposable client = (IDisposable)cf.CreateChannel())
{
    ((IServiceInterface)client).CallTheMethod();
}
```

I find this ugly. So :

- Do I really need to dispose it ? I mean that may be it is disposed when you disposed the factory (if the factory keeps a reference to every object it has created maybe) ?
- If yes, do you have a better way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very complex issue. Even by [Microsoft's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/27/performance-improvement-of-wcf-client-proxy-creation-and-best-practices.aspx) own admission, disposing of channel factories was a bad design which was changed multiple times so short answer is no, you need to use something alternative to it.

Here is an [alternative](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/dontdontuse-using.html) method to disposing.

Comment: you didn't really answer my question, but you provide me good reading, I accept your answer. Thanks.